# How to manage library conflict? (same package, different version)

Tags: java, dependencies, classpath

related: [manage conflict on java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182235/manage-conflict-on-java-classpath)

also related: [Java Classloader - how to reference different versions of a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553567/java-classloader-how-to-reference-different-versions-of-a-jar)

I have two jar files in my  which in each own has it own dependency included in jar file but both of them is in different version.

`a.jar -> has c.class/c2.class/c3.class/.. version 0.3 in it`

`b.jar -> has c.class/c2.class/c3.class/.. version 1.0 in it`

But when I tried to use both of them in the same project. It seems like it only use c.class from one jar but not another. This turn out to be a problem since API is very different in both version. Is there anyway to tell them to use a c.class just from its respective jar ? I can't modified a.jar and b.jar here.

btw. After quick search it seems like people suggest OSGI and classloader but I know next to nothing about it which should be the quickest way to deal with it ? (already read a little bit about classloader but still not sure how to use it).

EDIT: I prefer to use original library they bundle with since I already evaluated those two jar separately (they are text mining tools with same back-end but the version is very different). Now I want to integrate both of them into one and try to make the environment close to original as possible.
Right now I follow Travis Webb's solution but I still wonder why the jar don't separate both set of library.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274317/mixing-different-versions-of-java-libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickest way:

Extract `a.jar`, delete the stuff you don't want, and re-jar it. A JAR is *identical* to a zip file, which means you can just create a normal zip file and rename it to a `.jar`.

btw, this is not your fault. Whoever you got those jars from are idiots, because they included external dependencies in with their releases, and they aren't supposed to do that.

Comment: thanks, I tried your solution and it worked although quite a little bit different from my original goal (separate their environment). btw. these program spawned from biomedical field where the normal software practice is next to non-existence.

Comment: I think we should be diligent enough to cross verify jars by ensuring that it serves only our interests .